# Need to pass over a data file using an Purrr::map_dfc

Tags: r, hdf5, purrr

I have code that works beautifully for 90% of my H5files. However, I have 3 files out of 200+ that have one column of data with a single extra entry, instead of 3212 it has 3213. I CANNOT go in and delete these in the files. I just need to either ignore that particular file completely or drop the extra entry.  U have tried pmap and map2 with no success. It loops over 5 files then opens them all into one data frame. 
I have tried using possibly() but that does nothing. I am unsure how to use tryCatch

```
i<- 0
      for(i in seq_along(files)) {
        name <- paste0("file_", i) 
       assign(name,files[[i]]) 


      } 

 H5_files<-lapply(files, H5Fopen)

file_list <- h5ls(H5_files[[1]])
TM_AU<- purrr::map2(H5_files, "/Diagnostics/TM_AU",  h5read)
  units <- purrr::map_char(TM_AU, "Units", H5Fopen)
  # time is contructed from the dt and t0 variables. So that the shots line up for comparison it must only be called once. 

  possible_length <-possibly(H5Fopen, otherwise= NA)
  TM_AU_df <-purrr::map_dfc(TM_AU, "Data", H5Fopen, possible_length) # I get the argument length here 
# Error: Argument 3 must be length 3312, not 3313 
  dt <-purrr::map_dbl(TM_AU, "dt", H5Fopen)
  t0 <-purrr::map_dbl(TM_AU, "t0", H5Fopen)
```

Comment: What do you get in `possible_length` ? You can use `keep` to keep only those files with length 3312 and then use `map_dfc`.

Comment: It gives the same error it does not change it so I am doing something wrong in the possibly function. I am trying to find reprex for H5 files so that I can use that in my example here but am not having any luck.

Comment: can you make a reprex for a toy dataset that doesn't use h5?  that might help isolate the problem - and if not, it'll at least allow others to work with a simple example.